# How to pass an argument to a UIPopovercontroller in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller

How to pass an argument to UIPopoverController in iOS From another view?Like when we display a media file in popover;we have to pass the file path of media file from some other view to popover.

Comment: try subclassing UIPopoverController and a property in it say NSString filepath...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UIPopoverController is expecting you to give it your own UIViewController to display. So you pass the arguments to your own view controller, then set the popover to display it.

An example... set up a view controller that will display a test image:

```
UIImageView *testImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"testImage"]];
UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[viewController setView:image];
```

Initialise the UIPopOverController with that view controller:

```
popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:viewController];
```

Then display it:

```
[popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:displayPopoverButton permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Remember that your popover controller can't be a local variable or it will be deallocated too early and the program will crash.

Answer (score 1):

You declare a property on the your popover controller and set it to the desired value when initializing it.